# Angular2 how to pass an array to component that is part of a reactive form

Tags: ionic2, angular2-forms, angular-reactive-forms

I am working with Angular2 reactive form (which is a resume form), there are a few fields on the form and then a component `qualifications` that i need to pass an array to (so that using loop i can display the qualifications of users).

This is how i am passing the data to the component `qualifications`

```
        <ion-list-header> Qualification & Education </ion-list-header>
        <div formArrayName="qualifications">
            <div *ngFor="let qualification of profileForm.controls.qualifications.controls; let i=index"
                 class="panel panel-default">
                <qualifications [group]="profileForm.controls.qualifications.controls[i]"></qualifications>
            </div>
        </div>
```

This is the html of a `qualifications` component

```
<div [formGroup]="qualificationForm">
    <ion-item padding>
        <ion-label stacked>Qualification</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="text" formControlName="position"></ion-input>
        <small [hidden]="qualificationForm.controls.position.valid" class="text-danger">
            Qualification is required
        </small>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item padding>
        <ion-label stacked>Institution</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="text" formControlName="location"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item padding>
        <ion-label stacked>Date</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="date" formControlName="at_date"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
</div>
```

This is how the qualification array looks like

```
0:{id: 1744687, location: "Singapore", position: "B Tech", at_date: "09/2014"}
1:{id: 1762435, location: "Singapore", position: "B Tech 2", at_date: "11/2014"}
2:{id: 1802837, location: "Singapore", position: "B Tech 3", at_date: "12/2016"}
```

I am not able to understand how to pass array of objects to this component so that it can display the qualifications in loop

In `ngOnInit` i am calling the `addQualification` function which is as following

```
addQualification() {
    const control = <FormArray>this.profileForm.controls['qualifications'];
    const addrCtrl = this.initAddress();
    control.push(addrCtrl);
}

initAddress() {
    return this.formBuilder.group({
        position: ['', Validators.required],
        location: [''],
        at_date: ['']
    });
}
```

The problem I am having is the form only display the first object of the array and is not looping through